# CakePHP 2.8, url rewrite not working(can access only home route)

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i have application that i got from another developer that is not present anymore, 
i managed to almost make it up and running but i can access only default route 
abcd.xyz/
anything added is causing 404 i inspected that this is apache2 configuration i have 2.4.4 version  and this are my .htaccess's

root dir

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

app dir:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

webroot:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

i have mod_rewrite enabled but this looks like it isn't
 any help is appreciated

[EDIT}

my 000-default.conf

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
     Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Allow from All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

my vhost.conf

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abc-cake2/app/webroot/
<Directory /var/www/abc-cake2/app/webroot/>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` in app dir should look like this by default:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, if you really have mod_rewrite enabled, please also check AllowOverride settings for your DocumentRoot in apache config.

Additional reading: [CakePHP 2.x - URL Rewriting](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html)

Comment: Please check if you can access any route by address: abc.xyz/index.php/[controller]/[action].